# eslint --fix introduces weird spaces in ES6 string template literals

Tags: ecmascript-6, eslint

When we ran `eslint --fix` on our codebase, it replaced a lot of string concatenations from our legacy code with template literals. This is great but it does so in a counter intuitive way.

```
//legacy
const mass = parseFloat(item.mass).toFixed(3) + 'kg';
//output after eslint
const mass = `${parseFloat(item.mass).toFixed(3)  }kg`;
```

Why are there 2 spaces here between the end of the expression and the `}` char? How would this be avoidable?

Comment: in eslint flie check 'indent' object. you must have 'ObjectExpression': <number of spaces>, remove that if you dont want, but it will reflect in all over the project.

Comment: if you dont want concatination, remove or set to false 'prefer-template' rule.

Comment: @Ariz How is the template literal an object expression?

Answer (score 1):

Inside your  eslintrc file check for rule

```
'template-curly-spacing': ['error', 'never']
```

try running eslint --fix again. I tried and it worked like charm